# How to add dashed text form field in flutter?

Tags: forms, text, flutter

I want my text form field to look like the pic below. There should be 6 underlined spaces to enter 6 digits.

I know there can be work around of adding 6 text form fields and keep changing focus and then save the final value by concatenating all the values but that seems too much. There has to be a very simple way for this!

[image]

Comment: Found packages pinput and pin_input_text_field